# ambiguous call to overloaded function IsDebuggerPresent

Tags: c++, mfc

> Error    1   error C2668: 'IsDebuggerPresent' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

```
if (ms_IMEHookFunction && !IsDebuggerPresent()) 
{
    RegisterHotKey(ms_window, ms_hotKeyId, 0, VK_F5);
}
```

How can fix it?

Comment: It seems that one function is declared without parameters and other function is declared with default arguments for its parameters. Simply do not use such two declarations in your program.:)

Comment: Doesn't the error message list what candidates make the call ambiguous?

Comment: The Win32 API only has one `IsDebuggerPresent()` function, and it has no parameters.  Any overloaded version would have to be coming from somewhere in your own code.